# Create a LogIn and Register using XMPP framework

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to make an XMPP LogIn and a Registration Page Separate one from another, the server is open fire based. Also I am NOT using inbound registration. I would like to underline that this is my first attempt to do something like this, my previous experience involves only working with NSSession to make a registration/ login. I want to say that I bought and read the Mastering The XMPP Framework book witted by Peter van de Put, but he explains only how to do it for an inbound registration/ login. 
Also other links that I come across: 
1 - similar answers between them

[XMPP Aklesh Rathaur answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783710/how-can-i-create-a-new-user-account-in-xmppframework-in-ios)
[XMPP Diego answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070076/xmppframework-how-to-register-a-new-user-account)

2 - tutorial

PS: The information that I need to send to the server when I sign up is: email, name and password when created
and when I sign in: email, password

[Building a Jabber Client for iOS](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190)
in this tutorial I don't understand how does the login take place since it only saves the users credentials in the NSUserDefaults.

You can download what I have implemented here (using an stackoverflow suggestion):
[my code so far and database structure picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58bev491kd5bni4/untitled%20folder.zip?dl=0)

UPDATE, this is the code that I am trying to use for registration:

-> .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "XMPP.h"
#import "XMPPRoster.h"

@interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, XMPPRosterDelegate, XMPPStreamDelegate>
{
    XMPPStream *xmppStream;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) XMPPStream *xmppStream;

@end
```

-> .m file

```
- (void)signUpButtonFunction{
    NSLog(@"SignUp function");

    [[self xmppStream] setHostName:@"IP_ADDRESS"];
    [[self xmppStream] setHostPort:5222];
    XMPPJID *jid=[XMPPJID jidWithString:emailTextField.text];
    [[self xmppStream] setMyJID:jid];
    [[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:3.0 error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"venkat"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"dfds"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"eref defg"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@bbc.com"]];

    [ xmppStream registerWithElements:elements error:nil];

}


//server connect delegate methods are not working at least it doesn't enter in them
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration" message:@"Registration Successful!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error{

    DDXMLElement *errorXML = [error elementForName:@"error"];
    NSString *errorCode  = [[errorXML attributeForName:@"code"] stringValue];

    NSString *regError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR :- %@",error.description];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration Failed!" message:regError delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"409"]){

        [alert setMessage:@"Username Already Exists!"];
    }   
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after search on the matter I found out that on the openFire can be installed a plugin that allows normal registration, so I have implemented the next method for the registration:

```
NSString *urlToCall = @"http://MyIP:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=BigSecretKey&username=testUser&password=testPass&name=testName&email=test@gmail.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToCall];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([responseString  isEqual: @"<result>ok</result>\r\n"]) {
    NSLog(@"user created");

} else {
   NSLog( @"user NOT created");
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please explain the code for login please